Rambam’s ancient writing spilled on by coffee
I heard a beautiful story of a Rabbi, who after being successful in business, decided to try to use his wealth to put together a research team to come up with a definitive edition of the Rambam's works, with resolutions to various competing "versions".
The business purchased an old original writing of the Rambam, and were privileged to be the first to study the text in order to resolve a girsa issue. He was so pleased with their purchase, he arranged that they laid it out one day for the whole company to come and take a look, and be one-on-one with an original writing of the Rambam.
One of the men in the company took his turn, walked in with his coffee, and accidentally spilled it all over the original writing and ruined it. He was so ashamed of himself, but without delay the Rabbi put his arms around him, apologized that his coffee spilled and brought him another one, showing how much he cared for others and didn’t want him to be embarrassed.
Does anyone know where this story is quoted and what the name of the Rabbi is?

Someone listens to Vayimaen :)

You've already received the answer that the story is about Rav Shabsai Frankel, but since you also asked where the story is quoted, another retelling of this event can be found here by Rebbetzin Tziporah Heller Gottlieb, whose daughter is (per that source) married to R'Frankel's nephew

The story is told that it was Rabbi Shabsel Frankel, of the famous Rambam-edition.
Refer to here
It happened after 1975. He found the manuscript in a Egyptian museum.

Thank you! Do you by chance know of the “original” source I.e if it was said or published by either the Rav himself or his helper or a family member (I know he said he heard it from a family member so did they ever publish it anywhere)?

Welcome! I think it is something that was told by the one that was there at the moment.

@ShtikaK'hodaah it wasn't mentioned at all by Rabbi Frankel. So much so that when the person who did it showed up to his shiva house after he passed away, he was introducing himself to the Rabbi's family as "the coffee guy" and they all had no idea what he was talking about.

@RabbiKaii wow thank you for adding that, incredibly humbling…B”H we should all have such humility

@ShtikaK'hodaah this story has indeed brought many to tears. I have amended the question to be truer to the original events. Please review my edit and modify/revert as you please. FYI I believe the employee who caused this wasn't even Jewish.

Shmuel, I think that actually he purchased it from Oxford (or another big UK university's) Library. They originally found it in the Cairo Geniza (iirc, or another famous geniza). It's worth noting they knew who he was, and how keen he was to get these manuscripts, so they charged him triple its going worth and he didn't even hesitate in buying it, simply to fix one letter in the Rambam.

@RabbiKaii Where are these details from?

@shmosel I heard it in a shiur from a person who did the research. This didn't happen long ago but without knowing anyone personally involved, is one of those stories that might be hard to "source", but let's see

@RabbiKaii wonderful additions. Thanks for letting us know. I only found out who it was but did not know he kept it a secret.

@Shmuel thanks for what you found! One more detail I remember - the cost of the writing was something like $300,000 in the end. A very expensive coffee!
